# Strange results using order by and limit

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I'm trying to set up a pagination using SQL. I want 3 results per page and here is what I have done :

```sql
SELECT mot_cle.* FROM mot_cle 
ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0; --Page 1

SELECT mot_cle.*  FROM mot_cle 
ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3; --Page 2

SELECT mot_cle.*  FROM mot_cle 
ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 6; --Page 3

SELECT mot_cle.* 
FROM mot_cle 
ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 9; --Page 4
```

I checked many times and this is not very complicated but my results are not really what I expected :

Page 1 :

```
+-----+--------+------+
| id  |  mot   | hits |
+-----+--------+------+
|   2 | test   |   46 |
|   1 | blabla |    5 |
| 475 | intro  |    3 |
+-----+--------+------+
```

Page 2 :

```
+-----+-------+------+
| id  |  mot  | hits |
+-----+-------+------+
| 478 | vrai  |    1 |
|  26 | ouest |    1 |
|  27 | serie |    1 |
+-----+-------+------+
```

Page 3 :

```
+-----+-------+------+
| id  |  mot  | hits |
+-----+-------+------+
|  27 | serie |    1 |
|  26 | ouest |    1 |
| 478 | vrai  |    1 |
+-----+-------+------+
```

Page 4 :

```
+-----+-------+------+
| id  |  mot  | hits |
+-----+-------+------+
|  27 | serie |    1 |
|  26 | ouest |    1 |
| 478 | vrai  |    1 |
+-----+-------+------+
```

As you can see, pages 2, 3 and 4 have the same results...
When I fetch the 4 pages in one :

```sql
SELECT mot_cle.*  FROM mot_cle 
ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Result :

```
+-----+-------------+------+
| id  |     mot     | hits |
+-----+-------------+------+
|   2 | test        |   46 |
|   1 | blabla      |    5 |
| 475 | intro       |    3 |
|  35 | acteurs     |    1 |
|  36 | milieu      |    1 |
|  37 | industriel  |    1 |
|  38 | plaire      |    1 |
|  39 | grandes     |    1 |
|  40 | ingenieries |    1 |
|  41 | francaises  |    1 |
|  34 | partenaire  |    1 |
|  33 | rthgyjhkj   |    1 |
|  32 | cool        |    1 |
|  31 | super       |    1 |
|  30 | vieux       |    1 |
|  29 | moteur      |    1 |
|  28 | yahoo       |    1 |
|  27 | serie       |    1 |
|  26 | ouest       |    1 |
| 478 | vrai        |    1 |
+-----+-------------+------+
```

Maybe I'm missing something or sorting results and using limit/offset are not compatible, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The behavior you're observing is within spec. What you're missing is a second expression in the `ORDER BY` clause, to make the order deterministic. The rows *are* being "ordered by" `hits`, but there's multiple rows with an *identical* value for `hits`. MySQL is free to return those rows with matching value of `hits` in any order it wants. To get those rows returned in a deterministic order, add some expressions to the ORDER BY clause, some combination of expressions that are unique for a row. It looks like the `id` column may be unique. E.g. **`... ORDER BY hits DESC, id DESC LIMIT ...`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange ordering bug (is it a bug?) in postgres when ordering two columns with identical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904766/strange-ordering-bug-is-it-a-bug-in-postgres-when-ordering-two-columns-with-i)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that the rows all have a hit count of `1`, therefore their position when using `ORDER BY hits` is non-deterministic. And since you execute a new query each time you access a page, the rows will be "scrambled" anew.

To keep your pages consistent, you could also order by their id:

```
SELECT mot_cle.* FROM mot_cle ORDER BY hits DESC, id ASC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0; --Page 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT` basically "aborts" the query once enough matching rows have been found. E.g. if you have `LIMIT 2`, then as soon as two rows which match the `join`/`where` clauses are found, the rest of the query goes away and you get those two rows.

But if you have an `ORDER BY` in there, then the ENTIRE matching result set is ordered, then the LIMIT is applied to that sorted set.

e.g. if you have some records that'd be returned as `5,10,203,3,92`, then

```
SELECT id ... LIMIT 2             ->    (5,10),203,3,92
                                        ^^^^^^---actual returned-to-client results
SELECT id ... ORDER BY id LIMIT 2 ->    3,5,10,92,203 -> (3,5),10,92,203
                                           ^^---internal-only results
                                                         ^^^^--actual returned-to-client results.
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
Limit 3 offset 0
Limit 3 offset 3
Limit 3 offset 6
Limit 3 offset 9
```

you should be able to use

```
Limit 0,3
Limit 3,3
Limit 6,3
Limit 9,3
```

to the same effect

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question asked.

Comment: Yes, this is alternative syntax for the `LIMIT` clause, but this doesn't explain the behavior being observed by OP. And making this change won't have any affect on the rows being returned.