# SQL ORDER BY date DESC doesn't return last record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I need to get a set of records from MySQL database ordered by field 'date' which contains date in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.
When I use sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 11 OFFSET ".$offset;
```

everything is sorted correctly but the last row is never returned.
When I use sql query without command `ORDER BY` all needed records are returned.

Query that returns all needed records from database:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id']." LIMIT 11 OFFSET ".$offset;
```

Issue is **not connected** with `LIMIT 11 OFFSET ".$offset` because even without this part of query the problem still exists.

What is this unusual behavior connected with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange results using order by and limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803067/strange-results-using-order-by-and-limit)

Comment: Are you saying you only get 10 rows in the first query, but 11 in the second?

Comment: The 'working' query returns an indeterminate set of records from the table. Also, the term `id` is usually reserved for a surrogate PRIMARY KEY, making your query very odd indeed.

Comment: Can you show the PHP execution? Do you get the same results when you execute in the DB interface?

Comment: The suggestion of @chris85 to check what results in db interface make me to check my php code more closely. It appeared that I decremented one variable unnecessarily. It was not a problem of sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL query turned out to be completly correct. It was a issue of PHP code whitch was executing this query. Problem is solved.

Comment: Great, but the query still doesn't make much sense :-(

Comment: One of variables was unnecessarily decremented during the process of presenting data and it caused that always one record was not presented. I checked if db interface returns correct data. The results were completly ok so i find out that there must be a problem with my php code.